# Show divergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x+\sqrt{x}+7}{x^2+2x+1} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, divergent-integrals

> $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x+\sqrt{x}+7}{x^2+2x+1} dx$$

How can I show that the following integral diverges by using the direct comparison test? Thanks in advance!

Comment: $$x>1\implies\frac{x+\sqrt{x}+7}{x^2+2x+1}>\frac{x}{x^2+2x+1}>\frac{x}{4x^2}=\frac1{4x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note,

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x+\sqrt{x}+7}{x^2+2x+1} dx>\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(x+1)^2} dx
=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+1}dx-\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} dx$$
$$=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+1}dx-\frac12$$

which is divergent because $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+1}dx$ is divergent.

Comment: I appreciate your help. However, I don't fully understand how you did this step: $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x}{(x+1)^2} dx
=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+1}dx-\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} dx$? This topic is relatively new for me.

Comment: I know that you divided the integral into two partial fractions but I am not sure how you got there.

Comment: @LudwigvonDrake - Note $\frac{x}{(x+1)^2} = \frac{x+1-1}{(x+1)^2}=\frac{1}{x+1}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

Answer (score 0):

For sure, the problem is at the upper bound.

Let $x=y^2$ to make
$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{x+\sqrt{x}+7}{x^2+2x+1} dx=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{2 y \left(y^2+y+7\right)}{\left(y^2+1\right)^2}\,dy$$

Use the long division for the integrand
$$\frac{2 y \left(y^2+y+7\right)}{\left(y^2+1\right)^2}=\frac{2}{y}+\frac{2}{y^2}+\cdots$$